# if text box First word "/" and Item description then form "itemsearch"

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0

If textbox first word "/" and Item description then form "itemsearch" show and "itemsearch"  textbox itemname = without "/" text that enter in last form

For Example:

/what is item
 in Itemsearch form textbox.text = **"what is item"**

Comment: Look at the `String.Trim` method.

Comment: Please read how to ask -  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Describe your problem and show what you have tried so far. This looks like you are asking us to solve a homework problem and you have typo's in your question.

Comment: Please use google translate or something next time, this is unreadable.

Comment: I ask you that **if textbarcode.text start with "/" then **itemsearch** show and in itemsearch form textbox.text = after "/" text 
else find form item where itemcode = textbox1.text

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler for LostFocus of the TextBox

**XAML**

```
<TextBox x:Name="tBox" LostFocus="tBox_LostFocus" ...
```

and handle it in your **code behind** file

```
private void tBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tBox.Text = tBox.Text.Trim('/');
    }
```

Anyway, if you want to implement a VIM-like search (looks sort of to me) you should save your search term without the / to a separate string. Users might find it confusing when the content of a recently filled out text box changes automatically

Comment: I ask you that if textbarcode.text start with "/" then **itemsearch.show** and in **itemsearch** form textbox.text = after "/" text else find form item where itemcode = textbox1.text

Comment: you already got the answer: use the Trim function. if it is now textbarcode.Text.Trim('/') or another text field does not matter, you should be able to adapt that to your needs. If this answer does not match your needs, you should re-formulate your question so that it is clear and understandable